# How to check if an object is deleted?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

For what I understood, I know that an object can be deleted by running `bpy.ops.object.delete()` when that object is active.

But how can I verify that the object is deleted?

For example:

```
o = bpy.context.active_object # object I want to delete
print(is_deleted(o)) # False
bpy.ops.object.delete()
print(is_deleted(o)) # True
```

What should I write in the function `is_deleted`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do it by object name

```
def is_deleted(o):
    return not (o.name in bpy.data.objects)

# or instead of a function,
# obj will be None if the object isn't found, 
# else it returns the obj reference
obj = bpy.data.objects.get(o.name)
```

Comment: Did you mean `o.name not in bpy.data.objects`?

Comment: And what if the object is deleted and a new one with the same name is created before I perform the verification, would that be a problem?

Comment: The delete operator is probably safer than removing objects via RNA methods. I don't know if it clears all references, but at least it won't fail if there are any users and I haven't seen any follow-up crashes unlike with RNA (which usually happens if users are cleared without clearing references). Other than that, I would do `bpy.data.objects["name"]` and catch a possible AttributeError, or use `.objects.get("name")` for performance reasons. BTW: it's impossible that a deletion occurs while your script is running, unless your script itself does that, because scripts run synchronous/blocking.

Comment: Did you test this thoroughly? Because Blender will not crash before it actually tries to dereference an invalid reference (dangling pointer). As far as I understand, you would need to scan through each and every datablock and check if there's a reference to the object you wanna delete and clear it (set to None), then user count should drop to zero and the object can be safely deleted.

Comment: I favour a succinct answer and have removed the extra noise.