# Object delete handler

Tags: python

Is there any way to call a function on object delete or on changing count of `bpy.data.objects`?
There is nothing suitable in `bpy.app.handlers` and I coudn't find something anywhere else.

Comment: could set up a scene_update handler to do this with a global dic or similar and check with something like this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34860/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-deleted?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I Tried to avoid scene_update handler because it calls too often but it's ok if this is an only option...

Comment: Could use a modal timer operator, or even a draw method to flag change.  The scene_update handler is AFAIK the "catch all" way to check on delete.

Comment: You can override the delete function. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/prevent-accidental-deletion-of-object/28933

Answer (score 3):

Piotr commented that you could override the Delete operator, as described for a different purpose in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28933/66651

I am using it to remove derivative objects. It works very well!

```
class delete_override(bpy.types.Operator):
    """delete objects and their derivatives"""
    bl_idname = "object.delete"
    bl_label = "Object Delete Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in context.selected_objects:

            # replace with your function:
            my_function(obj)

            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(delete_override)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(delete_override)
```

Comment: What if two add-ons override like this?

Comment: @Ray, good point! The later one would win. Good enough for experiments, not good enough for release quality.