# How do I create a delete handler in Blender 3.5 onwards

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

In the past I have been able to execute code before deleting an object in blender using the method described in this post:

[Object delete handler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66065/object-delete-handler)

As far as i know this method wont work in blender 3.5 onwards since object.delete cant be unregistered. Is there an alternative way to create a delete handler or run code before deleting an object that wont require users to remap hotkeys?